# What potentiometer should I use for my led strip?

Tags: resistors

I have a led strip, this led strip is consuming about 2.5A @ 12V.
*Before, I was using an Arduino to modulate the intensity of the light with PWM but I realized that a simple circuit would be even better for what I want.*

I am wondering what potentiometer should I use to get the same result than when I was using the PWM, because when I was using the PWM of the Arduino, I often putted it to "1 out of 255" to get a really soft light, so what is the equivalent resistance to "1 out of 255" ? Am I right to think that my potentiometer will have to go from 0 ohms to this specific resistance ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD6L92.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use PWM? Is it just because the arduino is big, while the potentiometer is small? The PWM solution is way better than the potentiometer in so many ways...

Comment: To give a good answer we need more details. What type of LEDs, and how are the LEDs arranged (how many LEDs in series, what series resistor).

Comment: Potentiometers don't like high current; you'd need a fairly chunky and expensive one for this.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want to shut current down to maybe 25mA (100:1) reduction you might be looking at a pot resistance of about 250 ohms ohms. Point 1

Point 2 is the power rating - with the pot at a setting that maybe controls half the amperage (1.25 amps) it might be dropping 3 V across it and that means a resistance of 2.4 ohms and a power dissipation of about 3.75 watts.

BUT, BUT, BUT, you can't get a pot that like this - a 10 watt pot is rated over its full end to end resistance - it aint rated at 3.75 watts for the first 2.4 ohms with a gradually smaller power rating as the pot wiper moved to centre then to the far end.

So you are left with a pot that can handle 3.75 watts for each 2.4 ohms of travel. Given that your pot needs to be probably about 250 ohms in total, that's a total power dissipation of 361 watts or something that looks like this: -

[image]

[Here](http://www.bonanzamarket.co.uk/listings/Ohmite-Rheostat-50ohm-2-45A-300-Watts-RNS50R/188839411?gpid=18283950120&gpkwd=&goog_pla=1&gclid=CNbk6ueKzL8CFWfHtAodLgEAHg) is the website you can buy it from. Below is one that looks cool but is also big and clunky. It's rated at 500 watts: -

[image]

It can be found [here](http://www.bonanzamarket.co.uk/listings/Bercostat-l500-cf-500W-Power-Resistance-Decade-Rotary-Rheostat-Resistor/185153689?gpid=18283950120&gpkwd=&goog_pla=1&gclid=CMSjyruLzL8CFRHHtAodzxMAjQ) and costs £52

I'd stick to using PWM.

Comment: Andy, 25mA over 250 Ohm drops 6V. Are you assuming that the LED strip still works at 6V?? IMO you can't make the calculation without knowing the details of the LED strip (how much voltage for the LEDs, how much for the series resistors).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen You are absolutely correct but I'm mainly playing devil's advocate in order to explain the main point about power dissipation - if it happens to be only 3V at 25mA then the pot resistance will be 120 ohms and the pot wattage might be about 200 watts.

Answer (score 0):

The Potentiometers that Andy aka mentioned are overkill.  You will probably need to disipate around 30 watts - still too much for a nice, small pot.
Stick with PWM, but you might want to use a dedicated circuit instead of the arduino.  [Something like the PWM-Circuit shown here](http://www.solorb.com/elect/pwm/pwm1/) would be about right.  It gives you a pot to control the brightness, but it uses PWM to drive the LEDs.

You could buy a similar kit [here.](http://www.apogeekits.com/electronic-kits-intermediate/pulse_width_modulator.htm)

Comment: Can you justify why you think my suggestions are overkill?

Comment: The LED strip is built to run on 2.5 A at 12Volts.  That is equivalent to a resistor of 4,8 Ohms. Given that we are still supplying the thing with only 12Volts, then if you put a resistor in line with the LED strip, the resistance will go up.  Less current, same voltage=lower power use.  The total cannot be more than the 30Watts that the LED strip alone would use. The LED strip has a (at the least) a resistor as a current limiter, so we can treat it as a resistive circuit and use Ohm's law on the whole thing.

Comment: you haven't read my answer correctly - the first few ohms of the pot **have** to be several watts rated, (like about 3.75 watts) AND you cannot buy a pot built like this - pots you can buy have every 2.4 ohms inevitably rated the same hence, for each 2.4 ohms of the pot (104 sections) the total power of the pot is 300 odd watts. I'm not saying it needs to dissipate that amount - I'm saying you have to choose a pot like this or it will burn when controlling 1 or 2 amps.

Comment: Ah.  I read it as an entirely different thing.  As I read it, you were estimating the disipation by a really squirrely method - but the squirrels were in my head.  You were estimating the smallest Rheostat that could carry the load for the brightest setting.