# What resistance is required to drop 12v 11A DC to compleate 0v?

Tags: potentiometer, voltage

Let's not lie. I'm a big fan of LEDs.
I have about a meter long strip (3.2W) plugged to a computer power supply through connector capable of supplying 12V and 11A.
I was about to buy a 10k Ohm potentiometer but i'm not sure if it would be able to compleately turn off the LEDs if needded.

So basically: I need a potentiometer that would be able compleately block the electricity from an LED strip. How can I calculate the required resistance?

Comment: Please forgive me if the question is inappropriate but I'm in a hurry.

Comment: There's a name for what you are trying to make: It's called a "rheostat." (You can google that to learn more.) Using a rheostat to control lighting usually is unsatisfactory, because a lot of power can be wasted in the resistance element.  If you try to use a small potentiometer as a rheostat to control a 3.2W lamp, then there's a good chance of you overheating the pot and burning it out. Dimmers for LED strips (which, you can buy pretty cheap on Amazon) typically work by [pulse-width modulation (PWM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation).

Comment: @SolomonSlow Suggesting that the OP use PWM is consistent with how this site works, but recommending a specific product is getting close to the line. If the OP **asked** us to recommend a specific product we would probably close the question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, Oops! Sorry.

Comment: use a switch to turn off the LED strip

Comment: the answer to your question is `zero ohms` ... a short circuit across the power supply output will bring 12V to 0V

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer, [What potentiometer should I use for my led strip?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121608/what-potentiometer-should-i-use-for-my-led-strip) it gives you the "resistance required" but pretty much tells you not to use it, due to power losses it is a bad solution.

A potentiometer will never completely stop the current going through the LED, but you can put in there one that drops the current to a value low enough that it "doesn't" emit light. I would ballpark that a current of 0.01mA (10uA) must be enough to stop it from shining.

There are better solutions to control the light intensity and turn it on and off, like, if you just want to turn it on/off, use a switch. If you want to control the intensity, you can use a rheostat (not recommended, because it will waste a lot of power), or a transistor, or even go with a 555 timer to generate a PWM to modulate the intensity of the LEDs.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are potentiometers that have an integral switch actuated at one end of their rotation; these were commonly used as combined power/volume knobs on radios in the past, though I don't know if that's still common.

Comment: I guess putting the potentiometer close to zero ohms will be the ok part, but as you reduce the LED brightness/current, you increase the resistance of the potentiometer and waste a lot of power (in the this case I would guess the peak would be around 1.6W of power losses). Also, when the resistance is big enough there is almost no current so it also doesn't waste power. The main problem is if he wants to dim the LED (otherwise he could use a common switch).

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying it's a _good_ idea. Just that they do exist.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a potentiometer that would be able compleately block the
>   electricity from an LED strip

Why not simply use a switch with necessary current rating? You can also a buy a relay board if you want to isolate it or control it via digital means (Arduino or a GPIO). Please also consider a minimum series resistance in series so as to not blow LEDs after certain time due to over current.

Comment: Would a 5k Ohm resistor be enough? Or is it pointless?

Comment: Everybody says it'll cause a lot of wasted power, will the resistor heat up?
If it's true, are there better ways to lower the current?

Comment: are you trying to dim the LEDs as well or Just On and OFF?

Comment: Yes, I need adjustable brightness.

Comment: http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-LED_Strip_Driver/ if you want to build your own with MOSFETs and a PWM signla (555 timer or arduino!), please look for already existing solutions adn ask if you have more questions